# Calling app.locals outside of app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Normally, by declaring `app.locals` variables, like below, I can then use the variable in jade templates.

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.locals.varName = 'blah blah'
```

---

I'm looking to move `app.local.varName` to an external file (ie: vars.js) and then import them back in app.js for use. I'm familiar with the export module/require system, but I don't know how to make the variables become "active" for use. This is what I've got so far:

```
// vars.js 
module.exports = {
   all : {
      var express = require('express');
      var app = express();          

      app.locals.varName = 'blah blah'
   }
}
```

and then import back into app.js:

```
// app.js
var variables = require('./vars');
var variables2 = variables.all()

variables2
```

However, my jade templates still don't recognize the `varName` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it, I figured out what I was looking for:

```
// vars.js 
module.exports = {
   all : function() {
      var siteName = 'blah blah'
      return siteName;
   }
};

// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

app.locals.whateverName = require('./vars').all();
```

And then, in jade templates you can simply call `=whateverName` to get the blah blah output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `all` in exports does not appear to be valid. But that should be easily fixed. The problem here could be because the locals get added into a separate app created from `all()` and not the one which you use in app.js. Try modifying your code like so (passing your in use `app`):

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var variables = require('./vars');
variables.all(app)
console.log(app.locals);
```

**vars.js**

```
module.exports = {
   all : function(app){
      app.locals.varName = 'blah blah'
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
{ [Function: locals]
  settings:
   { 'x-powered-by': true,
     etag: true,
     env: 'development',
     'subdomain offset': 2,
     view: [Function: View],
     views: '/home/hadoop/views',
     'jsonp callback name': 'callback',
     'json spaces': 2 },
  varName: 'blah blah' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var app = express();
var variables = require('./vars')(app);
```

and

```
module.exports =function(app) {
    app.locals.varName = 'blah blah'
}
```